# thread safe object state manipulation in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to do the following in a multi-threaded environment (it does not implement the solution correctly at the moment but you can get the intent)

```
struct object {
    object() : numReaders(0) {}
    void tryRead() {
       numReaders++;
       if(!isDestroyed) {
           // do something
       }
       numReaders--;
    }

    void destroy() {
       if(numReaders == 0) {
           // <- if there is a reader here we have a problem
           isDestroyed = 1;
       } else {
           // wait until all readers are done and destroy
       }
    }
    std::atomic<int> numReaders;
    std::atomic<int> isDestroyed;
};
```

this sure looks like a std::shared_mutex or a reader/writer lock problem. Is this particular problem solvable in the context of c++11 in a clean and short way (without copying implementations from c++14 or smth) and without using third party libraries?

## A solution attempt:

OK, so I wrote something like this (destroy in the case above is a writer, and try read is a reader). There are 3 solutions, the 2nd and 3rd one trying to create less boiler plate code and 3rd also tried to be exception safe (if an exception is thrown no deadlock occurs). However, running 2nd solution works just fine, the 3rd one gets a deadlock, although seemingly 3rd is just a slighly modified 2nd, relying on the fact that C++ would call destructor at the end of the scope.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reader/writer solution 1
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Doer {

    std::mutex requestLock_;
    std::atomic<int> numRequests_;
    std::condition_variable hasNoRequests_;

public:
    Doer()
        : numRequests_(0)
    {
    }
    void reader()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_);
            numRequests_++;
        }

        std::cout << "read" << std::endl;

        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_);
            numRequests_--;
            // notify a potential writer that read is over
        }
        hasNoRequests_.notify_one();
    }

    void writer()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_, std::defer_lock_t());
        hasNoRequests_.wait(guard, [this]() {return numRequests_ == 0; });

        std::cout << std::endl << "write" << std::endl;

        guard.unlock();
        // wake up only 1 writer
        hasNoRequests_.notify_one();
    }
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reader/writer solution 2
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class SmartDoer {
    std::mutex requestLock_;
    std::atomic<int> numRequests_;
    std::condition_variable hasNoRequests_;

    std::function<void()> startRead_;
    std::function<void()> finishRead_;

    std::function<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>()> startWrite_;
    std::function<void(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>)> finishWrite_;

public:
    SmartDoer() : numRequests_(0)
    {
        startRead_ = [this]() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_);
            std::cout << "start read" << std::endl;
            numRequests_++;
        };

        finishRead_ = [this]() {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_);
                numRequests_--;
                std::cout << "finish read" << std::endl;
            }
            // notify a potential writer that read is over
            hasNoRequests_.notify_one();
        };

        startWrite_ = [this]() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_, std::defer_lock_t());
            hasNoRequests_.wait(guard, [this]() {return numRequests_ == 0; });
            std::cout << "start write" << std::endl;
            return guard;
        };

        finishWrite_ = [this](std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&& guard) {
            std::cout << "finish write" << std::endl;
            guard.unlock();
            // wake up only 1 writer
            hasNoRequests_.notify_one();
        };
    }
    void reader()
    {
        startRead_();

        std::cout << "read" << std::endl;

        finishRead_();
    }

    void writer()
    {
        auto result = startWrite_();

        std::cout << std::endl << "write" << std::endl;

        finishWrite_(std::move(result));
    }
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Reader/writer solution 3
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename Start, typename Finish>
class ScopeGuard {
public:
    ScopeGuard(Start& start, Finish& finish)
        : start_(start)
        , finish_(finish)
        , engaged_(true)
    {
        auto result_ = start_();
    }

    ~ScopeGuard()
    {
        if (engaged_) {
            std::bind(finish_, std::move(result_));
        }
    }
    void release()
    {
        engaged_ = false;
    }

private:
    std::result_of<Start()> result_;
    Start start_;
    Finish finish_;
    bool engaged_;
};

template <typename Start, typename Finish>
class VoidScopeGuard {
public:
    VoidScopeGuard(Start& start, Finish& finish)
        : start_(start)
        , finish_(finish)
        , engaged_(true)
    {
        start_();
    }

    ~VoidScopeGuard()
    {
        if (engaged_) {
            finish_();
        }
    }
    void release()
    {
        engaged_ = false;
    }

private:
    Start start_;
    Finish finish_;
    bool engaged_;
};

class TheSmartestDoer {
    std::mutex requestLock_;
    std::atomic<int> numRequests_;
    std::condition_variable hasNoRequests_;

    std::function<void()> startRead_;
    std::function<void()> finishRead_;

    std::function<std::unique_lock<std::mutex>()> startWrite_;
    std::function<void(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&&)> finishWrite_;

public:
    TheSmartestDoer() : numRequests_(0)
    {
        startRead_ = [this]() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_);
            std::cout << "start read" << std::endl;
            numRequests_++;
        };

        finishRead_ = [this]() {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_);
                numRequests_--;
                std::cout << "finish read" << std::endl;
            }
            // notify a potential writer that read is over
            hasNoRequests_.notify_one();
        };

        startWrite_ = [this]() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(requestLock_, std::defer_lock_t());
            hasNoRequests_.wait(guard, [this]() {return numRequests_ == 0; });
            std::cout << "start write" << std::endl;
            return guard;
        };

        finishWrite_ = [this](std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&& guard) {
            std::cout << "finish write" << std::endl;
            guard.unlock();
            // wake up only 1 writer
            hasNoRequests_.notify_one();
        };
    }
    void reader()
    {
        VoidScopeGuard<decltype(startRead_), decltype(finishRead_)> guard(startRead_, finishRead_);

        std::cout << "read" << std::endl;
    }

    void writer()
    {
        ScopeGuard<decltype(startWrite_), decltype(finishWrite_)> guard(startWrite_, finishWrite_);

        std::cout << std::endl << "write" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TheSmartestDoer doit;
    std::vector<std::thread> write(10000);
    for (int i = 0; i < write.size(); i++) {
        write[i] = std::thread(&TheSmartestDoer::writer, &doit);
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> read(10000);
    for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++) {
        read[i] = std::thread(&TheSmartestDoer::reader, &doit);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < write.size(); i++) {
        write[i].join();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < read.size(); i++) {
        read[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB I have replaced valid with isDestroyed

Comment: Does `destroy()` just do nothing if there are pending readers? Is it more like `try_destroy()`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I have modified the code to reflect the intent better

Comment: You cannot "wait" in a userspace program (other than by busy-looping, which you never want to do). "Waiting" is property of the operating system's scheduler, and you need an operating system service to allow you to wait, such as blocking on mutex. You cannot implement a mutex in userspace (although some people [want to](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4195.pdf)).

Comment: @KerrekSB I never said it is not allowed to use a std::mutex that is available in c++11. The code is only given to show the intent. Wait was meant as block

Comment: The primitive that implements "wait until a condition becomes true" is called `std::condition_variable`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am aware of that, no need to troll. The problem is that if you wait with a mutex in `destroy`, it means there should be that same mutex inside tryRead too, otherwise after the condition `numReaders=0` is satisfied and another reader comes there is a problem. If there is a mutex lock in `tryRead`, then the solution does not permit multiple threads to read

Comment: The lock only needs to be held while incrementing and decrementing `numReaders` - not for the whole body of the method.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is a good point actually, thanks

Comment: is destroy supposed to be starvable?

Comment: @Yakk ideally no. Do you know how to avoid starvation here?

Comment: I haven't looked at it, but If you want to have the functionality of a shared_mutex, then why don't you want to copy the implementation and refactor it according to your needs? Or does it contain platform specific calls?

Comment: @MikeMB lets say its hard to convince certain people that it is a way to go. This problem is solvable by a shared_mutex, however as IgorTandetnik pointer out, there is no need for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use *weak reference* paradigm, that is object's reference which do not prevent object from being deleted. c++11 has `std::weak_ptr<>` class for that paradigm:

```
#include <memory>    

class Object {...};

std::weak_ptr<Object> wptr; // Weak reference for use in (reader) threads

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Object> sptr; // Strong reference, determine lifetime of the object

    //...
    sptr = std::make_shared<Object>(...);// Create object and store reference to it
    wptr = sptr;

    //...
    sptr.reset(); // Mark object to be destroyed. Since that moment weak reference is treated as expired, no one can access object via it.
}

void reader()
{
     std::shared_ptr<Object> tptr = wptr.lock(); // Temporary create strong reference from the weak one
     if(tptr)
     {
          // Do something with object. It won't be deleted while 'tptr' is alive

     }
}
```

Both std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr are already prepared for multithreaded usage.

Comment: you still need an atomic way to check a shared_ptr and then lock it for the duration of usage I suppose, even in read

Comment: @iggy: No, additional atomics aren't needed. `wptr.lock()` *atomically* checks object's existence and return `shared_ptr` on success. While that returing reference is alive, object cannot be deleted. (Object will be deleted only when **last** `shared_ptr`, pointed to it, will be reseted or destroyed.)

Comment: ok, this is interesting. It works just exactly right for my use case.